# How can I get an Electron and Socket.io app to run in a thin client architecture?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, electron, thin-client

I created an Electron for a tiny company that connects to a Socket.io server. This app obtains the username of the logged in user and the MAC address and sends this info to the server for processing. All of this is working fine with regular desktops. Now, another company wants the same app, but they have a thin client architecture. Is there a way to get the app to run in this kind of architecture?

I am having a hart time figuring it out. I have never dealt with thin clients.

1) In the thin client architecture, would I have my socket.io server code and the app in the same server then? If they are in the same server, how could I get the app to connect to the socket.io server? They are in the same machine, so I am confused.

2) One problem is the app can't obtain the MAC of the thin client because once executed from the thin client it will end up getting the MAC of the server. Is there a way to obtain the MAC of the thin client using Node.js? Is there another way of using Node to recognize some sort of id for the thin client?

I would like the thin client to log in to the server, execute my app automatically, connect to the socket.io server, and send to it the username of the logged in user and the MAC address of the thin client. Is this possible? Do you have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the serverside code of the library for your server.  E.g. node express.

Then you have to use the client side code of the library in a client side application. E.g. electron

Electron is a combination of node and chromium and you have to install the final build on the clients machine(s).

Of course, you can do all the things you ask about. Just read the socket.io [docs](https://socket.io/docs/). Its very easy, you can do it by specifying the host IP and listening/emitting events.